# Inserting Data to Wix via JSON/REST API: WD_PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: permissions, velo

I'm trying to insert data to my Wix collection using the API. I'm using a POST function and am posting a JSON document. It's supposed to simply add a new row to a database containing 1 value.

Here is the `http-functions.js` which I can trigger without issues (it's more or less a copy of the example from the documentation):

```
import {created, serverError} from 'wix-http-functions';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

export function post_peopleCount(request) {
  let options = {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  // get the request body
  return request.body.text()
    .then( (body) => {
      // insert the item in a collection
      return wixData.insert("NumberOfPeopleDB", JSON.parse(body));
    } )
    .then( (results) => {
      options.body = {
        "inserted": results
      };
      return created(options);
    } )
    // something went wrong
    .catch( (error) => {
      options.body = {
        "error": error
      };
      return serverError(options);
    } );
}
```

The database looks like this:

[image: wix data collection table]

and the `JSON` I am posting looks like this:

[image: Postman HTTP Post request]

But the Error I am getting is:

[image: Wix HTTP post error]

But the permissions I have set for the collection is:

[image]

Do you know why I might be getting that `"WD_PERMISSION_DENIED"` and 500 Server Error? (The data does not get entered.)

Thanks!

Comment: just tested your exact code (without any authorization parameters) and it worked for me. what do you have on your authorization?

Comment: Thanks @Shan for your reply. I have tried with and without Authorization parameters in Postman, but get the same error.

Comment: Also the Wix site event logs seem to remain empty: https://www.wix.com/dashboard/xxxxxx/settings/monitoring/site-events

Comment: I have also tried adding the `suppressAuth` parameter, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

My friend, its not related to creating a collection from scratch it is because of the permissions set to this collection once created. You fixed that by not noticing :).

Permission need to be given in order to perform such queries.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, if I create a new collection (= table) from scratch, it works. I also changed the field `value` in the collection to `people`, maybe `value` is a reserved term. Nevertheless, now it seems to work:

[image]

So if you run into the same problem: Try recreating the collections from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The critical thing for me which has not been mentioned yet is that you need to set the collection to have form-like permissions so that anyone has permission to submit data to the collection.